# mysql insert into table from csv - drop first row

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to insert a csv file into a table and instruct the query to always ignore the first row from the csv file.  Users will be uploading files but the first row will be the column headings so I need the query to ignore the first row.  My script looks like this at the moment:

```
<?php
include 'datalogin.php';

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileCSV"]["tmp_name"],
      "quiz/" . $_FILES["fileCSV"]["name"]);

    $objCSV = fopen("quiz/".$_FILES["fileCSV"]["name"], "r");
        while (($objArr = fgetcsv($objCSV, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $strSQL = "INSERT INTO ex_question1 ";
        $strSQL .="(id,tn,qnr,qtype,pic,question,option1,option2,option3,option4) ";
        $strSQL .="VALUES ";
        $strSQL .="('".$objArr[0]."','".$objArr[1]."','".$objArr[2]."','".$objArr[3]."','".$objArr[4]."','".$objArr[5]."','".$objArr[6]."','".$objArr[7]."','".$objArr[8]."','".$objArr[9]."') ";
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    }
    fclose($objCSV);

    echo "Import completed.";
?>
```

Comment: You might want to investigate LOAD DATA INFILE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call `fgetcsv($objCSV, 1000, ",")` once before going into the loop:

```
 $objCSV = fopen("quiz/".$_FILES["fileCSV"]["name"], "r");
 fgetcsv($objCSV, 1000, ","); // skip first row
 while (($objArr = fgetcsv($objCSV, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO ex_question1 ";
    $strSQL .="(id,tn,qnr,qtype,pic,question,option1,option2,option3,option4) ";
    $strSQL .="VALUES ";
    $strSQL .="('".$objArr[0]."','".$objArr[1]."','".$objArr[2]."','".$objArr[3]."','".$objArr[4]."','".$objArr[5]."','".$objArr[6]."','".$objArr[7]."','".$objArr[8]."','".$objArr[9]."') ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
}
fclose($objCSV);
```

NB. your code is prone to SQL injections, please escape your input variables properly or use prepared statements!

Answer (score 2):

Consider even `LOAD DATA` command and `IGNORE` option

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html
```